# Want to add new filter in project

Tags: jhipster

I am working on hipster i have to add a new filter in my project but their is not web.xml file is avalible in project so where i am add filter with mapping.

this is filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't use a web.xml configuration on JHipster, we use the new Java Configuration for this.

Have a look at the generated "WebConfigurer" class to have examples of configured filters, for example the GZip filter.

Comment: Any examples I can follow like the examples from these tuckey rules? https://github.com/bdunklau/LittleBlueBird/wiki/URL-Rewriting-and-HTML5-in-AngularJS

Comment: Hi Julian, without web.xml, how can web-containers recognize and start the application?