# How to configure logback context-param using jHipster?

Tags: spring, jhipster, logback, web.xml

Fact 1: in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933998/want-to-add-new-filter-in-project) answer it is mentioned that the web.xml file has been replaced by the (generated) WebConfigurer class.

Fact 2: in the [logback documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#webShutdownHook) it is explained that, in order to avoid the logback facility shutting down before the application shutdown is completed, which would cause loss of logging messages, the web.xml file should be edited by adding the following stanza:

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>logbackDisableServletContainerInitializer</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Putting it all together, how can I set this configuration parameter while using jHipster?

Bonus question(s): how are the contents of the web.xml file mapped to the WebConfigurer class's contents? Can the WebConfigurer be customized during the generation phase, or should it be edited manually after generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported [in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886587/how-to-add-context-file-from-wildfly-to-jhipster?rq=1), the web.xml file can be found (and edited) in the "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF" folder, although it is discouraged to use it. However, there does not seem to be another way to operate in this case.